# PowerTOP "cpufreq_stats failed" and "Devfreq not enabled" running --auto-tone

Tags: 18.10, fan, powertop

Basically, I'm trying to reduce the thermals of an Ubuntu install and trying everything. Quiet as can be in Windows 10 except for gaming, as it should be; Ubuntu fans rev up to 75-100% doing simple tasks.

Anyway, going down the list of things to try and PowerTOP is one of them.

Ran `sudo powertop --calibrate --html` enough times to have enough measurements for doing `--auto-tune`. Was getting errors related to there not being enough measurements.

Now when I run `sudo powertop --auto-tune` I just get the following output. Isn't clear to me if it is working, but seem like it isn't:

```
modprobe cpufreq_stats failedLoaded 435 prior measurements
RAPL device for cpu 0
RAPL Using PowerCap Sysfs : Domain Mask f
RAPL device for cpu 0
RAPL Using PowerCap Sysfs : Domain Mask f
Devfreq not enabled
glob returned GLOB_ABORTED
Leaving PowerTOP
```

So what gives here? Googling isn't helping much.

Otherwise, I've tried `tlp` and a few other things. Only marginally help in reducing fan noise.

Comment: If you're on a laptop you may be interested in [notebook fan control](https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc)

Comment: Yes, on a laptop. I'll check this out, thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem as you with same error - had to --calibrate then reboot then --calibrate again and then --auto-tune
All worked then